# Command line app location? (OSX)

Tags: applications, command-line, geolocation

I wrote a small tool as a cmd tool. Where should it be placed? Which paths are automatically scanned for searching an app? I want to avoid absolute path, because I have to track it on every system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Terminal type `echo $PATH` and press Enter.  It will display your `PATH` Environment Variable.

Example:

```
 $ echo $PATH
 $ /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
 $
```

While you could place it in any of the locations listed nonetheless it's a good suggestion that you place it in `/usr/local/bin` as the other locations are used by the OS.  In a Terminal see `man hier` for an explanation of the layout of the filesystem in this respect.

On my system I have hundreds of scripts I've written, over the years, and use many on an ongoing basis so I created a directory in the *root* "`/`" directory called `scripts` and place everything there and added `/scripts` to my `PATH` by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/scripts` to my `~/.profile` file.

So my `PATH` is as follows:

```
 $ echo $PATH
 $ /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/scrips
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual Unix way for your scripts is /usr/local/bin for scripts that all users on the system can use and if for only you then in somewhere under your home directory often ~/bin

You need to make sure both of these directories art on your PATH environment variable preferably before system paths do if your write a script with the same one as a system one then your one gets run.

e.g in you shell (usually in ~/.bashrc)

```
export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```